# Docker container start("docker run") but stops inmmediately (ASP .NET MVC api-REST solution)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I created a MVC proyect in ASP .NET with local cosmos database simulation. I created a Dockerfile, and the docker image. After that I created and started my container "excited" to "up" but stops inmmediately. No fail message.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime

ARG solution

WORKDIR /local-proyect

COPY $solution .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Local.Proyect.Core.dll"]
```

How to do like don't stop my container after start?

My docker commands:

```
 docker build . -t proyect-image --build-arg solution=*.sln

Successfully built 50a0dc393959
Successfully tagged proyect-image:latest

docker run -d --name proyect-container proyect-image
d67ab234e260d67c2325789aaacb226586370e83907696036747365cc1e83b8b
```

After docker ps -a, I can see that only is excited, my .csproj(not all):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>f54b9509-6ab6-4bd3-bc3a-10764b4c927f</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

dotnet --info:

```
SDK de .NET Core (reflejando cualquier global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: Are you sure your application can run well locally?

Comment: Yes, using docker ps -a I can see all my containers that I created

Comment: But you said you run the image and it exit immediately. I'm not clear what is the issue happen to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that de my project exe.dll was not well. I forgot to change(build and publish) my project.

To do:

```
dotne clean
dotnet build -c release
dotnet publish -c release
```